# "Unable to open the database file". Do I have to put the full physical location of sqlite database when developing C# Console application

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sqlite

I have created a Sqlite database `mydatabase.sqlite` and placed it in my `App_Data` folder inside the console application project. I am getting an error:

> Unable to open the database file

when developing a console application using sqlite and C#.

When I am using

```
string cs = @"Data Source=App_Data\mydatabase.sqlite;Version=3";
```

I am getting

> Unable to open the database file error;

But when I am using

```
string cs = @"Data Source=C:\Users\UP_SW02\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\App_Data\mydatabase.sqlite;Version=3";
```

The application is running properly.

Is there any possibility to use Sqlite Data Source not using full physical location?

Thank you..

Comment: You should use always a full path for any files. Any relative path depends on the current directory of the process and that can change. Best option is to build the full path during runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All non-rooted paths used inside a program are relative to the folder in which the application is started. Note that **this is not necessarily the folder that the application itself is in.** You have to be very careful with such paths.

What you seem to be after is the folder relative to your own application. There's a simple method for getting that. If you have the `Windows.Forms` namespace included in your project, you can get the executable's path from `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath`:

```
// Get app folder
String appFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
// Combine with sqlite db path
String dbPath = Path.Combine(appFolder, @"App_Data\mydatabase.sqlite");
// Build connection string
string cs = String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Version={1}", dbPath, 3);
```

An alternative for `Application.ExecutablePath` if you're not using a Windows forms program is `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`, from the `System.Reflection` namespace.

Comment: As he asked the console application doesn't have `Application` by default , the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` should be referenced ..

Comment: Yes, it took some time to look up the non-forms alternative. I added it now. Though you can perfectly reference the Windows.Forms namespace in a console application, you know. There is nothing preventing that. Just like you can use the VB namespace tools in C#. Not many people seem to realize that.

Comment: Yes there is no preventing to add `Windows.Forms` dll I just want mentioned it is not in console app by default.

Comment: Well, I did mention the namespace requirement from the start. Also, oddly, the question _is_ tagged with "winforms"...

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get folder's relative path in a connection string is to simply add |DataDirectory|.

before

```
string cs = @"Data Source=App_Data\mydatabase.sqlite;Version=3";
```

after

```
string cs = @"DataSource=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\mydatabase.sqlite;Version=3";
```

Comment: Interesting. Though, by default, this resolves to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, which, as far as I understand it, is still the folder the application is _ran from_; not necessarily the folder the program is _located in_.

Comment: Guess it will just depend on his own config. I meant that he can just use the Data Directory attribute to get a relative path on the current domain if the App_Data is there.
Anyway, I will edit my answer, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Ah, nevermind. It seems `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` indeed resolves to the folder the program's exe file is in. Good solution; upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way SQlite needs to full path address but you can resolve it with two solutions:

1- Save connection path in config file.

2- Get `App_Data` folder path by `GetFolderPath` method like:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

So your code would be like:

```
var fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "mydatabase.sqlite");
string sqliteConnection = string.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;Timeout=2;", fileName);
```

3- Or the easy way is :

```
string sqlitePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/App_Data/mydatabase.sqlite";
```

Comment: The question's working example has "App_Data" as subfolder of the program's own path, though. It's not a system folder they're after.

Comment: Not sure if adding `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to the front of a relative path has any effect... that should be default system behaviour.